# How do I detect changes made by a trigger on a single row using the OracleDataApdater

Tags: .net, oracle, dataadapter

Im updateing a single row of data using the OracleDataAdapter and datatable. Calling the .update method of the apdapter works fine however a database trigger updates one of the field values after the update.  This causes me the problem where the datatable is out of sync with the database.

Possible Solutions
I could requery the data after each update statement or use oracle dependency fires however I believe that the best method would be to have the DataTable update itself to that of the changed values, but how do I do this?  I have tried using using the oracle command builder for the update statement and then alter each of the parameters to be inputoutput, this has not worked i have also tried hooking into the events of RowUpdated but unsure as to what to look at there.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Two Ways i Can think of

1- Either start maintaing history of table changes so that , you can query your history table for update mades.

2- Maintain a timestamp column so that when you are going to update the record , you can match the timestamp of records to check whether the record you are updating is stale or not if its stale either throw Concurrency exception or reload the data.